AOS Library and SEO Indexing Issues
I am currently working on optimizing our website's performance and search engine visibility, and I've noticed some indexing issues and other SEO-related challenges while using the AOS (Animate On Scroll) library on our site. Specifically, it appears that content dependent on AOS for visibility may not be indexed effectively by Google. Could you provide insights into how AOS might affect SEO and content indexing?
Example:
<link href="/home/assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/home/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
 <h1 data-aos="fade-up">Welcome to Our Website!</h1>
    <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
        We are excited to share our content with you. Scroll down to see more animations!
    </p>

